# Laravel job check site if online

Tags: php, laravel

On every post I have url a website. I need get status and check every hour if this site is online. How I can do it with queues Laravel? I have a job CheckPostSite:

```
public function handle()
{
$allposts = Post::all();

foreach($allposts as $post) {
     if($this->checkOnline($post->site_url) {
          $post->website_online = true;
          $post->save();
     }
}
}

private function checkOnline($domain) {
$curlInit = curl_init($domain);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

//get answer
$response = curl_exec($curlInit);

curl_close($curlInit);
if ($response) return true;
return false;
}
```

I'm doing everything right? Or not? I have 10000+ posts in database.

Comment: This question wouldn't exist if everything worked fine, right? What is your actual question, what doesn't work?

Comment: Not Laravel concern but if you have several urls to check, take a look at Rolling Curl wrapper. There are some "easy to use" libs like https://github.com/marcushat/RollingCurlX. I use it to check several urls with this script : https://github.com/Ljz7/EverDomainChecker. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To do the actual scheduling - follow the steps in the docs
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands
with the pertinent 2 steps:

1. Ensure you a cron job on your server to actually run the job scheduler (not your job, the schedule that will kick of your job(s)

   - - - - - cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
2. Add your own job to the schedule method of Console/Kernel.php

   $schedule->job(new CheckPostSite())->hourly();

But whilst you are developing you can test the job by just using tinker:

```
php artisan tinker
$job = new CheckPostSite()
$job->handle()
```